# Is my proof of the quotient-remainder theorem correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing

A few days ago, my professor explained the quotient-remainder theorem, although he did not prove it. I thought it might be fun to give it a shot myself, but I am only in my first year of university, so it could easily be very wrong. Anyways, if anyone with a bit more knowledge and background than me could let me know if my proof is correct, that'd be really appreciated! Thanks!

(Also I'm sorry in advance if this ends up being a stunning display of the Dunning-Kruger effect)

The Quotient Remainder Theorem:

> For all integers $n$ and $d>0$, there exists unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $0\le r<d$ and $n=qd+r$.
> Or in other words:
> $$\forall_{n,\ d\ \in\ \mathbb{Z},\ d>0}:\exists_{\ q,\ r\ \in\ \mathbb{Z},\ 0\le r<d}:(n=qd+r)\wedge(\forall_{x,\ y\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}\ \backslash\ \{q,\ r\},\ 0\le y<d}:n\neq dx+y)$$

My Proof:

> Assume $n,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $d>0$. Then, $\exists_{k\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}:dk\le n<d(k+1)$.
> By dividing this inequality by $d$, this gives $k\le \frac{n}{d}<k+1$.
> Therefore, $k=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor$.

> By subtracting $dk$ from both sides, $dk\le n<d(k+1)$ implies $0\le n-dk<d$.
> $n,d,k\in\mathbb{Z}$, therefore $n-dk\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Let $j=n-dk$. Then, $0\le j<d$ and $j\in\mathbb{Z}$.
> Finally, $j=n-dk$ gives $n=dk+j$.

> Therefore, for $q=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor$ and $r=n-dq$, it has now been shown that $q,r\in\mathbb{Z},\ 0\le r<d$ and $n=qd+r$.
> Therefore the first conjunct has been proven, and it remains to show that $q$ and $r$ are unique.

> Assume there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $n=dx+y$, where $x\ne q$, $y\ne r$, and $0\le y<d$, or in other words, that $q$ and $r$ are not unique.
> $d,y>0$ and $n=dx+y$ imply $dx\le n$.
> The above inequality and $0\le y<d$ give that $dx\le n<d(x+1)$.
> Dividing by d, one gets $x\le \frac{n}{d}<x+1$.
> Therefore $x=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor\implies x=q$.
> This implies that $n=dq+y$ which gives $y=n-dq\implies y=r$.
> Therefore $n=dx+y$ if and only if $x=q$ and $y=r$.
> Therefore the assertion that $q$ and $r$ are not unique is false.

> Therefore the quotient remainder theorem is true.

Comment: Why are you formatting the stuff that follows $\forall$ and $\exists$ as *subscripts* of those symbols? Quite frankly, it looks weird. Replace the "_"s with spaces and it will look better.

Comment: Your proof is okay, but it relies on the existence and properties of non-integer numbers, which are generally developed after this theorem, thus risking circular reasoning. You should try to restate with demanding the existence of $\frac nd$ or using the greatest integer function. This is not as hard as it sounds. You've only used them here as an intellectual crutch. They are not needed for your argument.

Comment: hmm ... that should have been "*without* demanding the existence of $\frac nd$".

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the feedback! First off, with regards to the formatting of the quantifiers, I thought that was how they're supposed to be formatted- my calculus professor last semester used a subscript like that, but you are right, especially when the statements after the predicates are so long, it'd definitely look better not to do it that way!  As for your second point, that makes a lot of sense, thanks for the feedback- I'm gonna look into the greatest integer function and finding another way to develop my argument besides $\frac{n}{d}$.